# Error handling in dart - Evaluating user input

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

I am try to evaluate the data type entered by the user so it won't break down user enters a string. so that I can tell the user to input a number.  I have tried several ways but I don't I understand the "try-catch" algorithm well.

```
 import "dart:io";

String prompt(String promptText) {
  print("${promptText}");
  String answer = stdin.readLineSync();
  return answer;
}

double promptDouble() {
  print("Enter your numbers");
  double myNum = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  return myNum;
}

void main() {
  String op = prompt("Enter an operation \n +\n -\n *\n /");

  double num1 = promptDouble();
  double num2 = promptDouble();

  
  switch (op) {
    case '+':
      print("The sum of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${num1 + num2} ");
      break;
    case '-':
      print("The difference of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${num1 - num2} ");
      break;
    case '*':
      print("The product of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${num1 * num2} ");
      break;
    case '/':
      print("The quotient of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${num1 / num2} ");
      break;

    default:
      print("Sucker! Invalid Operator.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `dart:io` and replaced it for a static input because i'm using dartpad.dev.

Wrap the lines you know that can give you an error in the `try` block, next you can handle the error in the `catch` block, where you have access to the `error`. In my case I've printed the error and set the `myNum` to 0

```
double promptDouble(String str) {
  
  print("Enter your numbers");
  double myNum;
  try {
    myNum = double.parse(str);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    myNum = 0;
  } 
  return myNum;
}

void main() {
  String op = '+';

  double num1 = promptDouble('10');
  double num2 = promptDouble('hello');

  
  switch (op) {
    case '+':
      print("The sum of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${num1 + num2} ");
      break;
    case '-':
      print("The difference of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${num1 - num2} ");
      break;
    case '*':
      print("The product of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${num1 * num2} ");
      break;
    case '/':
      print("The quotient of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${num1 / num2} ");
      break;

    default:
      print("Sucker! Invalid Operator.");
  }
}
```

in your case yo could simply change the promptDouble function:

```
double promptDouble() {
  print("Enter your numbers");
  double myNum;
  try {
    myNum = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    myNum = 0;
  }
  return myNum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped... I am trying to modify to work on every input because it seems to work on the function but not the variable. I really appreciate your help